# AWS: Mounting a template disk with Batch / ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, mount

I am using AWS Batch but wish to increase the disk space available to my containers. I am using CloudFormation to create the stack, and I have added an EC2::LaunchTemplate to add a 100GB disk to my instance:  (extract from the stack)

```
BigDiskTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: '/dev/xvdcz'
            Ebs:
              Encrypted: true
              VolumeSize: 100
              VolumeType: gp2
      LaunchTemplateName: BigDiskTemplate
  MyComputeEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment'
    Properties:
      Type: MANAGED
      ComputeEnvironmentName: MyEnv
      ComputeResources:
        Type: EC2
        MinvCpus: 0
        DesiredvCpus: 0
        MaxvCpus: 256
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateName: BigDiskTemplate
        InstanceTypes:
          - optimal
          - c5.large
        Subnets:
          - !Ref Subnet
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        InstanceRole: !Ref IamInstanceProfile
      ServiceRole: !Ref BatchServiceRole
}
```

Yes, I want the disk to be ephemeral.  Yes I know some of the EC2 instances support larger disks, but I also want to do this with GPU instances.

When I run `lsblk` in the container, I get:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1       259:0    0  100G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1   259:6    0  100G  0 part 
nvme0n1       259:1    0    8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:2    0    8G  0 part /etc/hosts
└─nvme0n1p128 259:3    0    1M  0 part
```

Great! There's my 100GB disk.
But I can't work out how to mount it.
Based on samples and tutorials (admittedly for EC2) a template disk should be mountable with something like:

```
file -s /dev/nvme1n1
mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1

mkdir /data
mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data
```

However most of these steps give an error. Such as "/dev/nvme1n1: cannot open `/dev/nvme1n1' (No such file or directory)"; "mkfs.xfs: No such file or directory"; "mount: /data: permission denied"
I have also tried different drive designations - eg. /dev/nvme1n1p1, nvme1n1, or /nvme1n1/nvme1n1p1

So how I mount this disk inside my container?
Is Docker a part of the problem?

Comment: You need to use sudo or a root shell.

Comment: This is inside a docker container - ie. root by default. Just to make sure I tried sudo (same result) - but note I had to install sudo into the container in order to use it.

Comment: You need to create the filesystem and mount it from outside of the container. You then bind mount it inside of the container with the `-v` flag for docker.

Comment: How do I do that?  lsblk from within the container is showing the disk.

Comment: @winwaed Hey, I'm facing the same issue. I'm not seeing the formatted disk when I ssh in to the instance but shell commands work fine when I do it manually. Could you share the working code of user data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you should take:

1. Attach the volume to the EC2 instance. Now `lsblk` should show the device.
2. Mount (and format) the device to a location like `/data`. Set permissions and so on.
3. In the task definition, declare a volume that points to `/data`.
4. In your container definition, declare a mount point.

You cannot / should not mount a device directly to a container.

---

#### Edit: Details on step 2

It is possible to add a user data script to your launch configuration. This way you can mount (and format) the devices. Take this script as an example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Device name. NOT block name like 'nvme0n1p1'.
device="/dev/sdp"

# Where to mount the device.
mountpoint="/data"

# Wait for device.
while [[ ! -b $(readlink -f ${device}) ]]; do
    echo "waiting for ${device}">&2; sleep 2;
done

# Format if not already formatted.
blkid $(readlink -f ${device}) || mkfs -t ext4 $(readlink -f ${device})

# Mount.
mkdir -p ${mountpoint}
mount $(readlink -f ${device}) ${mountpoint}
chmod 666 ${mountpoint}

# Persist the volume in /etc/fstab so it gets mounted again.
echo "$(readlink -f ${device}) ${mountpoint} ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like I'm doing #1, and #4. I think I've tried #3 but not convinced I'm doing it correctly. How do I go about #2? I'm not using EC2 directly, just the LaunchType in the compute environment (for the tasks) and the LaunchTemplate (both above).    I've just found AWS::ECS::VolumeAttachment in the docs but this requires a running instance?   It all seems very complicated - all I want is for my AWS Batch containers to run with more (ephemeral) disk space!

Comment: You can include a user data in your launch configuration. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Just acknowledging your answer - it is helping a lot and I feel like I'm making progress. At the moment /data is mounting from /dev/nvme0n1p1 and shows 8GB, but lsblk still shows above (in the container). df does not show any 100GB partitions.  I'm trying to find diagnostics/logging for the userdata - a typo or poor formatting could easily mess things up;  and also trying to use the launchtemplate to create a regular ec2 instance and log in to that to have a poke around.

Comment: Are you using Terraform or Cloudformation? Remember that you have to explicitly declare the volume in the task definition. Take a look at this for example: <https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition>

Comment: And in the container definition you have to refer to the volume declared in the task definition. It is definitely more convoluted than a docker-compose file

Comment: Using CloudFormation. I've got to the log file. The error is with mount:  "mount: /dev/nvme1n1 is already mounted or /mydatadisk busy" (I changed /data to mydatadisk incase there was an unlikely clash).  About to try: https://serverfault.com/questions/1027275/unable-to-mount-device which describes what I'm seeing in my log diagnostics

Comment: what step are you failing at exactly or to frame it differently: what point have you reached so far successfully?

Comment: I have the first half of your script running, and set to send output to a log (I could post the log but Comments aren't big enough!). The error is on the call to mount:  "mount: /dev/nvme1n1 is already mounted or /mydatadisk busy" (I changed /data to /mydatadisk). The log also includes calls to lsblk,df, and findmnt immediately the call to mount. That serverfault question didn't help. I'm going to change the device name next. I notice that inside the container, that /dev/nvme0n1p1 (ie. the default 8GB) is being mounted on /mydatadisk.

Comment: Yes, my final issue was that I was using a device name of "/dev/xvdcz" when I should have used "/dev/sdp" or similar. I had seen references to this being the device name for mounted disks like this. Looking at the diagnostic output from lsblk, I think /dev/xvdcz was merely overriding docker-related disk, and not producing a new disk/partition for user mounting (I now see 3: my 100GB is now called nvme2n1 ). Inside the container, df shows my /mydatadisk to be 100GB!  Excellent! Thanks for the help!

Comment: And for anyone else reading this, I also had to wrap the above script in a MIME wrapper in order to incorporate it in situ in the CloudFormation script.